# in android how to put exit or close button on tabitems of an android tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, tabitem

I have an android app with `TabLayout` , I create `TabItems` and assign them to my `TabLayout` Dynamically with code in my MainActivity , in one of my `Fragments`, which is the `Fragment` for a `TabItem` , i have a button . what I want is when that button is clicked, its `TabItem` closes and destroys, how can I achieve that?
extra explanation: bellow is my `MainActivity.java` Code ( where most of my code for creating dynamic `TabItems` exists :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ContactsFragment.CallBacks {

    public static List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> fragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
        return fragments;
    }

    public List<String> getFragmentsTitle() {
        return fragmentsTitle;
    }

    public void addToFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
    }

    public void addToFragmentsTitle(String title) {
        fragmentsTitle.add(title);
    }

    public Fragment getFragmentsWithPosition(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    public String getFragmentsTitleWithPosition(int position) {
        return fragmentsTitle.get(position);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page_drawer);
        this.tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        this.viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        SetUpViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    }

    public void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter((getSupportFragmentManager()));
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new SignInFragment(),"ورود");
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new ContactsFragment(),"ارتباطات");
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new RegisterFragment(),"ثبت نام");
        viewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void send_user_object() {
        /* this is the implementation of abstract function defined
         in one of my tab , in which it has a button and when
         button is clicked i want the tab to be removed . */
    }

    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        public void AddFragmentPage(Fragment frag,String title) {
            MainActivity.this.addToFragments(frag);
            MainActivity.this.addToFragmentsTitle(title);
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return MainActivity.this.getFragmentsWithPosition(position);
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return MainActivity.this.getFragmentsTitleWithPosition(position);
        }


        public int getCount() {
            List<Fragment> frag = MainActivity.this.getFragments();
            return frag.size();
        }
    }



}
```

in one of my predefined tabs , i have a listview , when user clickes on an item on the list view , the detail of the item opens in a new tab , then user can see the detail by clicking on that tab . what i want is how user can close ( destroy ) that detail tab about one of items ? ( remember it is creating dynamically )
how can I remove ( close ) the `TabItem` with Click of a Button in that TabItem Fragment?
Plase help me , thank you beforehand .

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to change horizontal navigation by adding another fragment. If it's not absolutely required by your customer, create a new fragment and just replace the current one like this:

```
Fragment detailsFragment=new ContactsFragment()
getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack("tag")
    .replace(R.id.containerName, detailsFragment, "another_tag")
    .commit()
```

At your detailsFragment your close button's clickListener just call `getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStack()` 
and it restores previous state.
Hope I could help you.

Comment: i have added a solution , but there is an strange problem , i can't remove the `TabItem` when i'm on that tab !! the program crashes . but i can call my `close_tabitem()` method , from menu or when i'm on another `tabitem`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by :

first ) creating an interface in the `UserDetailFragment`, which you all know for communication with `MainActivity`, I had to do that.

but for what did I need communicating with the `MainActivity` ?
Answer : as you see in my code , my FragmentPagerAdapter class is defined there , and i needed my `public List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();` and `public static List<String> fragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();` that i had saved my fragments into them , and also `mytabLayout`.

Seconde ) i had to define `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(){}` with its method `OnTabSelected()` , i needed that because i get the current index of the tab using `addOnTabSelectedListener(){}` .

Third ) i defined `removeTabPage(int position)` in the FragmentPagerAdapter .

Forth ) i created a method as bellow ( which is the implementation of the abstract method of `UserDetailFragment` interface.

```
@Override
    public void close_tabitem() {
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(tabposition_number);
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Adapter.removeTabPage(tabposition_number);
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and here is my whole code for: `MainActivity.Java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ContactsFragment.CallBacks, UserDetailFragment.DetailCallBacks {

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    public static List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> fragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    int tabposition_number;

    public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
        return fragments;
    }

    public List<String> getFragmentsTitle() {
        return fragmentsTitle;
    }

    public void addToFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
    }

    public void addToFragmentsTitle(String title) {
        fragmentsTitle.add(title);
    }

    public Fragment getFragmentsWithPosition(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    public String getFragmentsTitleWithPosition(int position) {
        return fragmentsTitle.get(position);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page_drawer);
        this.tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        this.viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        SetUpViewPager(viewPager);
        this.toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                tabposition_number = tab.getPosition();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }

    public void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter((getSupportFragmentManager()));
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new SignInFragment(),"ورود");
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new ContactsFragment(),"ارتباطات");
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(new RegisterFragment(),"ثبت نام");

        viewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void send_user_object(UserObject userObject) {
//        tabLayout.removeTabAt(tabposition_number);
//        myViewPagerAdapter.remove

    }

    @Override
    public void create_user_detail_tab(UserObject userObject) {
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        UserDetailFragment userDetailFragment = new UserDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name",userObject.getName());
        bundle.putString("family",userObject.getFamily());
        bundle.putString("email",userObject.getEmail());
        userDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(userDetailFragment,userObject.getName());
        viewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void close_tabitem() {
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(tabposition_number);
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Adapter.removeTabPage(tabposition_number);
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        public void removeTabPage(int position) {
                fragments.remove(position);
                fragmentsTitle.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void AddFragmentPage(Fragment frag,String title) {
            MainActivity.this.addToFragments(frag);
            MainActivity.this.addToFragmentsTitle(title);
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return MainActivity.this.getFragmentsWithPosition(position);
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return MainActivity.this.getFragmentsTitleWithPosition(position);
        }


        public int getCount() {
            List<Fragment> frag = MainActivity.this.getFragments();
            return frag.size();
        }
    }



}
```

and here is the `UserDetailFragment.Java` , which acts as my `TabItem` :

```
public class UserDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    DetailCallBacks detailCallBacks;

    public UserDetailFragment() {}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_detail_fragment,null);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Button closebtn = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_close_button);
        closebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                detailCallBacks.close_tabitem();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        detailCallBacks = (DetailCallBacks)context;
    }

    public interface DetailCallBacks {
        public void close_tabitem();
    }

}
```

Hope It Helps You.
But do remember, you can not use this `button`. put the button in some other `tabitem` or in the `menu`.

or you can use :

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
tab.select();
```

to change the tabitem and then fire the event .
enjoy .....